# C++ multiple operators: assign A or B not equal to C

Tags: c++

I am currently learning from an SDL2/OpenGL2 example code, for [ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui). Then, I ran into a line (and a few more alike) as shown below. I believe this part binds SDL mouse events to IMGUI API. However, I do not quite understand how it works.

```
io.MouseDown[0] = g_MousePressed[0] || (mouseMask & SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)) != 0
```

where,

```
ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
bool mouseDown[5]; // a member of ImGuiIO struct
static bool g_MousePressed[3] = { false, false, false };
Uint32 mouseMask = SDL_GetMouseState(&mx, &my);
```

(I hope above is enough information...)

What makes me the most confused is the the last part, not equal to 0. I could understand it, if it was a simple assignment of the result of an And and an Or operations. However, there is not equal to zero following at the end and I have not seen this before. I would like to get some help to understand this code please.

Comment: This a standart bitmask approach, google "bitmask C++". Comparing with non-zero means that given value match the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expression != 0
```

is a boolean expression and thus evaluates to either `true` or `false` which can be converted to integer values of `0` or `1`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr size_t SDL_BUTTON = 5;
    for (size_t mouseMask = 0; mouseMask < 16; ++mouseMask) {
        std::cout << mouseMask << ' '
                  << (mouseMask & SDL_BUTTON)  << ' '
                  << ((mouseMask & SDL_BUTTON) != 0) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/jcmosg

Since `||` is the logical or operator, we are performing a logical comparison that tests whether `io.MouseDown != 0` *or* `(mouseMask & SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)) != 0` and yields a boolean value (true or false) promoted to whatever type `io.mouseDown[0]` is.

The code could actually have been written as:

```
io.MouseDown[0] = g_MousePressed[0] || (mouseMask & SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT))
```

or

```
const bool wasPressed = g_mousePressed[0];
const bool newPress = mouseMask & SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT);
const either = (wasPressed == true) || (newPress == true);
io.MouseDown[0] = either;
```

or

```
if (g_mousePressed[0])
    io.MouseDown[0] = 1;
else if (mouseMask & SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT))
    io.MouseDown[0] = 1;
else
    io.MouseDown[0] = 0;
```

See http://ideone.com/TAadn2

If you are intending to learn, find yourself a good sandbox (an empty project file or an online ide like ideone.com etc) and teach yourself to experiment with pieces of code you don't immediately understand.

Comment: `0 or 1` is identically `true`.

Comment: @Ruslan didn't get what you mean't at first, I removed those two lines, they didn't disambiguate anything as they'd been intended to.

Comment: I did not know that there was sandbox for C++! Thanks everyone for kind answers. It seems easy once I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

An expression `a = b || c!=0` means `a = (b!=0) || (c!=0)`. In boolean logic, `b` and `b!=0` are equivalent. That's what I think the most confusing part. Once this is understood, there should be no problem.

Note that this expression should not be confused with `a=b|c!=0`, where `|` is a binary operation called "bit-wise or", as opposed to the logical operation `||`, which is the logical "or". When doing `b|c!=0`, `c!=0` is calculated first to yield a logical value `0` or `1`, then `b|0` or `b|1` is calculated to do nothing (first case) or reset the last bit of the binary code of `b` to 1 (second case). Finally, that result is assigned to `a`. In this case, `b` and `b!=0` are not equivalent, because the bit-wise or `|` is used instead of the logical or `||`.

Similarly, `&` is the "bit-wise and" operator, while `&&` is the logical "and". These two should not be confused either.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `!=` has a higher precedence than `||`, so the whole expression is indeed a simple assignment of the result of an OR.

The `!=0` part is a way to turn the result of applying a bitmask into bool, as @AlekDepler said. Funny thing is its pretty much redundant (if `mouseMask` is of built-in integral type) as implicit conversion from say `int` to `bool` works exactly like `!=0`.